# How to persist entity with Spring Transactions and EntityManager with multithreading?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, transactions

I've encountered a problem during my multithreading tests of some simple app.
Application is written in spring-boot. I would like to ask for advice.
And before you read my code - I'm sorry for it's quality, this can be a little bit of a spaghetti code. I was testing a lot of options...

I have a service class that's only job is to update row count if entity exists or create new with incremented row count. Only difference from normal cases is that primaryKey is a String and is not autogenerated. Also main rule is to not loose single execution of updateCount (so no rollbacks).

```
@Service
public class SomeEntityServiceRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    public synchronized SomeEntity updateCount(String primaryKeyString) {

        SomeEntity entity = entityManager.find(SomeEntity.class, primaryKeyString, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

        if (entity == null) {
            try {
                entity = createNewEntity(login);
                return entity;
            } catch (Exception e){
                entityManager.refresh(entity);
                entity.incrementCount();
                entityManager.persist(entity);
                entityManager.flush();
                return entity;
            }
        }

        entityManager.refresh(entity);
        entity.incrementCount();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        return entity;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    synchronized SomeEntity createNewEntity(String primaryKeyString) {
        SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(primaryKeyString);
        entity.incrementCount();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

My EntityClass is:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    private String primaryKeyString;

    @Column(name = "COUNT", nullable = false)
    private long count;

    public void incrementCount(){
        this.count++;
    }

    //rest of the code
```

And my test case is (THREADS_COUNT is set to 100, service repository is Autowired):

```
@Test
    void testPessimisticLock() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS_COUNT + 10); 
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(THREADS_COUNT);
        SomeEntity entity = null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= THREADS_COUNT; i++) {
            service.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    serviceRepository.updateCount("SOMETHING");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                latch.countDown();
            });
        }
        latch.await();

        entity = serviceRepository.updateCount("SOMETHING"); // one additional execute for return
        Assertions.assertEquals(THREADS_COUNT + 1, entity.getCount());

    }
```

It works fine 90% of the time. Synchronized works well, transaction management also in most of the cases. But when two transactions managed by two threads wants to CREATE new entity - there is an error as first thread is not able to commit to database fast enough second starts new transaction and entityManager.find() method finds null.

So error log is like:

1. "Unique index or primary key violation:"
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to generate refresh event with null object
3. org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <101> but was: <100>

My entityManager is context-based, transactions are managed by container.

I have no idea how to prevent two transactions from two different threads to be executed exactly after each other. As from what I understand is that METHOD is synchronized, but transaction can be a little bit longer than method itself, as it's managed by external container methods and processes so the actual state in DBMS is not instant after flush.

I'm happy to get any help as this is a little bit to complicated topic for my skills.
I'm using Apache Derby Embedded (file) database.

Answer (score 1):

Test is done in single transaction, with rollback at the end. So you need something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(...)
@DataJpaTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ConcurrentTest {

    ....

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        final TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

        template.executeWithoutResult(transactionStatus -> {
            // init data
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testConcurrent() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testConcurrent");

        final int COUNT = 10;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(COUNT);
        List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                final TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
                template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

                try {
                    // code 
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                    throw exc;
                }


                return null;
            });
        }

        executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
    }

}
```